# How to remove Notes & Attachments from all layouts now that I have Files and Enhanced Notes?

Tags: page-layout, related-list, notes

Is there an easier way than to go to each Page Layout in Salesforce and remove manually from each? like maybe to un check something on the profile or the User?
I already have Files and also Enhanced Notes, and I have migrated my data already but still users are seeing it on the layouts and it's really tiring to go 1 by 1 to remove it from each.

Comment: I was testing for you but had to do my own work unfortunately. I have had some success in the past downloading meta-data via the IDE, in this case, VS Code. Then I would edit my package.xml to try to pull down page layouts and use REGEX to search the layouts and remove the bits I don't want and then re-upload them. I wasn't able to finish testing so I don't know if this will work for page layouts though. I just wanted to put a comment so that someone can pick up where i left off and give it a try or if they have more knowledge of meta-data api then I do.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to like my answer...

You have to manually go into each layout and remove the related list. It'll be annoying and tiring, but it's the only way to be done short of some fancy custom code/metadata manipulation which might take as long to develop and be more risky.